# Is my CakePHP Session login secure?

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I don't know how to use AuthComponent then this is the way I do user authentication with multiple roles is as follows:

There is 3 roles: Administrators, Resales and Clients.. one controller for each one, for individual views, and this is my `beforeFilter` for each Role/Controller:

`AdministratorsController:`

```
function beforeFilter(){
    if (!$this->isAuth('Administrator'))
        $this->redirect('/');
}
```

`AppController:`

```
function isAuth($strRole = NULL){
    $data = $this->Session->read('User'); 

    if (!$this->Session->check('User') || (!is_null($strRole) && $data['Role']['nome'] != $strRole))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

In `UsersController` I do only authentication checking if `$this->Session->read('User')` exists, if the user exists, he gets all info and put in Session like this: `$this->Session->write('User', $user);` assuming that `$user` is the find from Model with all user information.

the question is, will I have problems? is that "right"? do not know if I was clear, if missing information, ask..

Comment: what sort of problems?

Comment: Maybe security.. difficult to maintain code (never been a problem so far, but I'd rather prevent)

Comment: the code above will not stop your house from burning down. other than that i dont know what you want answered

Comment: I want to know if the logic is correct, if there is another way to do that.. should I really migrate to AuthComponent? there is a way to do this thing in Auth? (one controller for each Role, because of separated views)

Comment: there are always other ways to do things

Comment: One controller for each Role in AuthComponent, is that possible? there is an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replicating logic the framework already implements for you.

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what

Taken from that page (you should still read it..):

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

The user data gets passed to it, no need to fetch the user data yourself.

And if you ever have to fetch the user data use $this->Auth->user():

```
// Some field
$this->Auth->user('someField');
// Whole data
$this->Auth->user();
```

If the session key ever changes for some reason all you direct calls to the Session->read('User') will be in trouble. A good and not so unlikely example here is when the application has to be extended with a 2nd auth adapter that is *not* using the session. Auth will know about the data, Session won't have it.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing almost the same thing.. I will to use Auth, thanks